# Clicking on a widget with Flutter inspector does not go to the code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I use android studio as an ide, when I clicked on a widget with inspactor, it would directly show where the code was, but it doesn't show it anymore, probably I broke some settings.
For 2 days I've been looking for the cause, I couldn't find it.there are topics related to this question, but most of them are unanswered

Methods I have tried: Flutter update, Android studio update, methods in other topics,I searched in the Android studio settings and couldn't find anything

Comment: I am facing the same problem. That's why I went back to it's one of previous version this way:
1. Go to the flutter directory (cd /Users/sony/development/flutter/bin)
2. git checkout -f 3.10.5
3. flutter --version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same problem. That's why I went back to it's one of previous version this way:

1. Go to the flutter directory (cd /Users/sony/development/flutter/bin)
2. git checkout -f 3.10.5
3. flutter --version

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, my problem has been solved flutter 3.13 I wonder why this happened, I hope it will be fixed in new updates.
by the way, those who have this problem can downgrade the version using cmd after downloading 'git' to downgrade the version.

Answer (score 0):

If your project name include without ascıı characters and also include space. Flutter ınspector can work , but select widget mode can't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

To fix the issue of the Android Studio inspector not showing the code for a widget, make sure that you are running the latest version of Android Studio and Flutter. Then, open the App Inspection window and select the Widget Inspector tab. Click on the widget that you want to inspect and the code should now be displayed in the Code pane. If the code is not displayed, try the following: make sure that the widget is part of the running app process, restart Android Studio, or clear the Android Studio cache and restart.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).